# NoClassDefFoundError: JspSourceDependent on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My application works fine on the dev server but when I upload it fails to start and I get the following exception in the logs: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceDependent`. So far it seems to be related to the jsp dependencies declared in my app which are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am missing something obvious here, and why does the app work fine in the dev environment but fail to start up in the production environment?

Comment: Is there a stack trace? That's not much to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception was due to the pre-compilation of JSPs using the jspc-maven-plugin which left tomcat-specific code in the pre-compiled classes. The solution was to remove the plugin from the pom and let appcfg do the pre-compiling before uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch to Jetty for your dev server.

Comment: I don't know down-voted this but it was very useful. When deploying to Jetty I got a different exception which, in the end, led me to the solution.